# What does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This problem comes from another equation on another question ([this one)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325140/the-sum-sum-k-0-infty-k-1-2k-is-zero).
I tried to split it in half but I found out that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$$
can't be divided.

Knowing that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
I wrote that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\sqrt[k] k}{2}\right)^k=\frac{1}{1-\frac{\sqrt k}{2}}=\frac{2}{2-\sqrt[k] k}$$

But that's not what I wanted. Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is NOT a geometric series.

Comment: The mistake you've made is that $\sqrt k^k \neq k$

Comment: $\sqrt{k}^k \neq k$ so that's where your last line of algebra went wrong

Comment: Have you tried calculating any partial sums?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn)

Comment: The mistake is not so much that $\sqrt[k]{k}\neq k$, but the series is NOT a geometric series. Also, notice that the right-hand side of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ is independent of the index $k$. (In other words, $x$ should be fixed and independent of $k$).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{k\over2^k}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty{k\over2^{k+1}}=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty{k-1\over2^k}=2S-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1\over2^k}=2S-2\\$$

Using the ratio test, we show that $S$ converges. Therefore, we are able to rearrange the above result to solve for $S$ which gives us the desired result of $S=2$.

Comment: This is only correct if you already know that $S$ exists (i.e. that the sum doesn't diverge). Otherwise, very nice!

Comment: Solid approach! +1

Answer (score 26):

Start with:
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k.$$
Then take derivative with respect to $x$.
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}.$$
Multiply by $x$.
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k}.$$
Now substitute $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: am I wrong? if you place $x=1/2$ then the summation will be negative.

Comment: @kelalaka I had a typo with a negative sign. It's fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I check that someone edited, and the community accepted. Your original answer was correct. Revering back is also possible.

Comment: Why did you change the index when you took the derivative of the series?

Comment: @Burt The initial series starts with $1+x+x^2+\dotsb$ so after taking the derivative we will have $0+1+2x+3x^2+\dotsb$. Since the first term is now $0$ so I changed the index to start with $1$ (the first non-zero term of the derived series).

Comment: does this only work for 0<x<1?

Answer (score 12):

You can also view it this way, which is quite intuitive.

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}
    &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{4}{16} + \frac{5}{32} + \cdots \\
    &= \frac12 + \Bigl(\frac14 + \frac14\Bigr) + \Bigl(\frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18\Bigr) + \Bigl(\frac1{16} + \frac1{16} + \frac1{16} + \frac1{16}\Bigr) + \cdots \\
    &= \Bigl(\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \frac1{16} + \cdots\Bigr) + \Bigl(\frac14 + \frac18 + \frac1{16} + \cdots\Bigr) + \Bigl(\frac18 + \frac1{16} + \cdots\Bigr) + \cdots \\
    &= 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \cdots \\
    &= 2.
\end{align*}

*We are able to rearrange the terms of the infinite series in this way because the series is absolutely convergent. It is important that we meet this condition, as without this we would not be able to reorder the terms of the series and group them in this way.*

Comment: Because the series is absolutely converge it, you can rearrange it however you want. So it’s pretty easy to make this argument rigorous.