# Does the sequence $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^2}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the sequence $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^2}$ converge absolutely?

I know that  $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ for $s >1 $ converges absolute. So is it possible to show the absolute convergence with that knowledge?

Comment: This sequence has positive terms, so it converges absolutely if and only if it is convergent...

Comment: A useful fact to prove is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ then for large enough $n$ (depending on $\epsilon$) we have $\log(n) < n^\epsilon$ (or even better $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{n^\epsilon} = 0$). In normal words: the logarithm grows slower towards $\infty$ than any power. You can use this to show that $\sum \frac{\log(n)}{n^p}$ converges for all $p>1$ (comparison test with the series you quote).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This sum converges. You might try to write 
$$\frac{\ln n}{n^2}=\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n} \cdot \frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}.$$
Apply the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}=0$ and compare your series by the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}}.$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does converge absolutely, we have by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence),
$$0\leq\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^2}\leq\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{x^2}dx=1.$$
(the latter integral is obtained by integration by parts)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cauchy Condensation test](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOotzxlrbKAhWLUI4KHX8MBwMQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCauchy_condensation_test&usg=AFQjCNH6M4EiJiCCRxJrK36jT6nuj-fzqQ&sig2=Sx5qPLRMvt1IazNfnY3xDg). The series is convergent iff the following series is convergent.

$$
{1\over\log_2e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{2^n\log_2 2^n\over 2^{2n}}={1\over\log_2e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n\over 2^n}
$$
The series above converges by ratio test and [sums to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325254/what-does-sum-k-0-infty-frack2k-converge-to/1325267#1325267) ${2\over\log_2e}$.