# Find the value of sum (n/2^n)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$. I must show that it converges to 2.

I was given a hint to take the derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and multiply by $x$ , which gives

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$ , or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$.

Clearly if I take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ , the series is  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Start from the identity $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^n = \dfrac1{1-x}$ which holds good for $x \in (0, 1)$, then follow the hint (on both sides of the identity).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was able to solve the problem with this identity,

Comment: Have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2

Comment: [Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = 2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2),
[Why does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$ converge to 2?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441481/why-does-sum-n-0-infty-fracn2n-converge-to-2),
[What does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$ converge to?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325254).
If you [search in approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%20k%20%7B2%5Ek%7D%24&p=1) you can find more questions about the same sum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that if $|x|<1$ then the original series converges with

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{1-x}.
$$

Computing the derivative and plugging in $x=\frac{1}{2}$ should hopefully seem easier now.