# Prove limit of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n/(2^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How do you prove the following limit?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{2^k}\right)=2$$

Do you need any theorems to prove it?

Comment: The limit is unnecessary as what is inside of the parenthesis does not depend on $n$ at all.  It is like saying $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(52)$...  What would make more sense is to write $\lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^b\frac{n}{2^n}\right)$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: [Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = 2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2),
[Why does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$ converge to 2?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441481/why-does-sum-n-0-infty-fracn2n-converge-to-2),
[What does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$ converge to?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325254).
If you [search in approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%20k%20%7B2%5Ek%7D%24&p=1) you can find more questions about the same sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may start with the standard **finite** evaluation:
$$
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ we have
$$
1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ by multiplying by $x$ and **by making** $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, **using $|x|<1$**, we get

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}. \tag3
$$ Then put $x:=\dfrac12$.

*Edit. One may observe we have avoided differentiating an infinite sum.*

Comment: Differentiating an infinite sum seems like the recipe of Coca-Cola.

Comment: @the_candyman quite a lot is known about swapping sum and differentiation...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM it was ironic

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$${\displaystyle {\frac {x}{(1-x)^{2}}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }nx^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!}$$

Answer (score 2):

> I thought it might be useful to present two ways forward that rely on elementary pre-calculus knowledge only.  To that end, we proceed.

**METHODOLOGY 1:**

Note that we can write $n=\sum_{m=1}^n (1)$.  Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^n(1) \,x^n\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty x^n\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{1-x}\\\\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY 2:**

Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$. Note that we can write

$$\begin{align} x S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n+1}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)x^{n+1}}-\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{S-x}-\color{red}{\frac{x^2}{1-x}}\\\\
(1-x)S&=x+\frac{x^2}{1-x}\\\\
S&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: I would have replaced 1/2 by x to get a more general result with no additional effort.

Comment: @martycohen Good suggestion;  edited accordingly.  I've also added a second pre-calculus approach.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

The series is obviously convergent. Set $S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$. This gives
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{S}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\ \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{S}{2}+1$$
and therefore
$$S=\frac{S}{2}+1$$
that is $S=2$.