# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was trying to find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$.

I tried like this $S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n+1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^n}) = 2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n} - 1$

So,$S = 2(S - \frac{1}{2}) - 1$

Implying $S =2$.

**EDIT:**

Also from many posts in the comment below I found a method of looking at the sum $\sum x^n$ and differentiating and plugging for $x$.

Is there any other method of looking at the problem and calculating the sum apart from the above method,may be it would be interesting to see different approaches to the same problem which may be used to visualize other problems based on summation of series?

Comment: How about doing $\sum nx^n$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: One might note some ambiguity with your sigma notation. I'd prefer to write$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n+1}{2^n}-\frac1{2^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)-1$$

Comment: [Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} =
2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2),
[Why does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$ converge to
2?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441481/why-does-sum-n-0-infty-fracn2n-converge-to-2),
[What does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$ converge
to?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325254).
If you [search in
approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%20k%20%7B2%5Ek%7D%24&p=1)
you can find more questions about the same sum.

Comment: Yes,I should have searched through approach0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply with $(2-1)$:
$$ (2-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^{-n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n2^{1-n}-n2^{-n})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)2^{-n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^{-n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2 ^{-n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Summing $x^n$ gives $\frac{1}{1-x}-1$, so summing $nx^{n-1}$ gives $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. Set $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the geometric series

$$\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u^n.$$

This series is uniformly convergent for $|u|\leq 1$, hence we can differentiate it with respect to $u$, in which $|u|\leq 1$.

$$-\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{} u^{n-1} \implies -\frac{u}{(1-u)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{} u^{n} .$$

Relate this sum to your sum, in which $u=1/2$. Note, that your series is starting at $n=2$ and this series is starting at $n=1$.